# redirecting the standard streams in Java

Tags: java

I can't understand how we can, for example, redirect/reset ***System.out*** by calling ***System.setOut(PrintStream out)***, when ***System.out*** is declared final?

***setOut(PrintStream out)*** supposedly reassigns ***System.out*** the value of the argument *out*, which should be impossible given that ***System.out*** is final.

Any explanation as to how that is so?

Comment: I just wish for that who down-voted my question to comment and tell me why that was so.., just to help me avoid any pitfalls/misuse in future questions. Thx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How that is possible?

`setOut` is implemented as

```
public static void setOut(PrintStream out) {
    checkIO();
    setOut0(out);
}
```

and `setOut0` is a method implemented in the native system (JVM) and so able to change the final field of System:

```
private static native void setOut0(PrintStream out);
```

Note: it is also possible to change a final field by reflection - e.g.change the value of an *immutable* String literal

Comment: I didn't understand.. can you please explain? Thx.

Comment: System is calling a system function (native library), a function implemented in the virtual machine - this can do almost anything (regarding the running java program).

Answer (score 3):

The in/out/err fields do not need to change.

They might simply wrap around another stream. Those wrapped streams have a default behavior - and when calling those setter methods you simply replace that "interal" stream.

Like: System.out uses "internal.out" - and using the setter you can change internal.out to user.out for example (just making up these names as example).

Comment: I thought of that, but doesn't it mean it will continue continue indefinitely since the argument passed to setOut() is of the same type (PrintStream), as each PrintStream is wrapping another PrintStream?

Comment: also worth mentioning that `setOut` is calling a native method, so it is able to do a lot of *maigc* behind th scenes, including changing a final (null) field: `public final static PrintStream out = null;`

Comment: @Searcher I don't get that comment. You replace the "inner" stream with another stream. The is no recursion here. Do you know those Russian "puppets" they were there is always another smaller one inside? Here it is different : there are only two puppets... You can replace the inner, the outer stays the same.

Comment: System.out is of type PrintStream, and if we say that an object of this type is actually a wrapper for another object, then in our case, and since that other object is also of type PrintStream, there will be a third, and a forth, .. , etc. Plus, Java documentation says setOut() "Reassigns the "standard" output stream."